# Batch File check on Network

Tags: batch-file, vpn

I'm trying to create a batch file that downloads zip files from a network location and then automatically unzip files and deletes zip containers.

I have a challenge in that this network location is only available when connected to the LAN/WLAN or via VPN (which I do a lot).

I would like to start the code by checking if the network folder is available (either VPN or LAN), so added a

```
if exist \\network\folder
    echo VPN ready
    Pause
    ) else (
    echo VPN not available
    Pause
    )
```

Which works great when online, but when I'm not I have a blinking cursor in the CMD prompt.

Can you please help?

Comment: There is a `(` missing at the end of your first line of code. However, the code should work. You are not ending up with a "frozen" console. The system is actually trying to access the remote drive and will eventually terminate showing the "echo VPN not available" message after trying it for a while (in my test case about 30 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Having recently had a similar issue, I believe it's because you need to ensure the brackets for the if/else statement are the correct place, and you are missing a `(` in your first line like so:

```
if exist \\network\folder (
    echo VPN ready
    Pause
) else (
    echo VPN not available
    Pause
)
```

Naturally if the path is not accessible, it will take a few moments for the timeout to occur before telling you the VPN is not available.

[image]